# PHPMailer, return SMTP code

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer;

```
$oPM->SMTPDebug   = 2;
$oPM->Debugoutput = 'html';

if ( !$oPM->send() ) echo "Mailer Error: " . $oPM->ErrorInfo;
else echo "Message sent!";
```

Once `$oPM->Send()` has ran, I would like to recive a SMTP Status Code, regardless of success/failure.

Playing with the `SMTPDebug` option, I can get it to return a string as followed;

`MAIL FROM command failed: 500 5.0.0 Envelope From Address of...`

I could grab the code from the string. But would really like to have the actual code returned.

Is this possible, or should I go down the strpos route? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get an SMTP code back directly from `send()` because PHPMailer is not necessarily using SMTP. `SMTPDebug` output isn't for production use; the readable error message will turn up in `$mail->ErrorInfo`. You can get more precise info from the SMTP instance after calling `send`:

```
$mail->getSMTPInstance()->getError();
```

which returns a structure like this:

```
[
    'error' => '',
    'detail' => '',
    'smtp_code' => '',
    'smtp_code_ex' => ''
]
```

Incidentally, the 5.0.0 error embedded in your example is completely useless for diagnostic purposes - all it means is "it didn't work". Unfortunately you'll find that many mail servers are just rubbish at reporting errors correctly, especially Exchange, so if you want to be more accurate, you will end up parsing strings.

Comment: Thanks for this really great answer. Point noted regarding using only the response code. I will save both, 'detail' + 'smtp_code' on failure. Thanks again!