# How to know send mail delivery status

Tags: email, send, status, email-delivery

Using PHPmailer how may I be able to know whether a sent mail delivered to the user or not. Actually I want to know the delivery status of the sent mail using PHP. Is it possible? Please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer, return SMTP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716144/phpmailer-return-smtp-code)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
if($mail->send()) {
  // Do something if email sent successfully
}
```

As I understand it, it would depend on your email service. If you are using something like MailGun's API, you could get a delivery status on that, but if you are just using a standard SMTP server, checking if the email sent successfully is about as far as you an go.